# DatePicker as TextString in ListItem

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik, radio-button

I would like to add to my RadioButtonList a ListItem displaying a DatePicker on select. How do I go about adding this in code please, I mean the DatePicker? The code below is my attempt at this but does not work

```
  Dim datepick As New  DatePicker
  With datepick 
       .ID = "RadDatePicker1"
       .MinDate = New DateTime(CLng("2006-01-01"))
       .SharedCalendarID = "sharedCalendar"
       .Width = New Unit(100)
   End With

   RBtnList.Items.Add(New ListItem(datepick, "Other"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To relate the picker with other asp control, you will definitely need some javascript to glue it. When I browsed the telerik demos a while ago, I spotted [this one](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/calendar/examples/datepicker/shareddatepicker/defaultcs.aspx?product=grid) and it may get you on the right track.